# Expo start works but Expo build apk does not

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am able to run my react-native app locally using `expo start --no-dev`. When I try to build the APK and install it, it installs succesfully but when I run it, the app just closes and I get the android error `frontend keeps stopping`.

app.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "displayName": "frontend",
  "expo": {
    "name": "frontend",
    "slug": "frontend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "android": {
      "package": "com.sri.showify",
      "versionCode": 1
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "~1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.9",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.5.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.10",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "^0.63.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.10.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.13.12",
    "use-state-with-callback": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```